# Django built-in templates tags gets unformatted when I save my html file in VS-code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, django-tagging

I'm using django built-in templates tags which are `{% load static %} {% extends 'base.html' %}`  etc. so whenever I'm saving my document by pressing `ctrl+s` the formatting which should be gets disturbed which causes errors:

```
Unclosed tag on line 1: 'block'. Looking for one of: endblock.
```

[image]

before saving the document the editor looks something like this:
[image]

but as soon as I save my document it becomes like this which results in the above mentioned error
[image]

any solution for that? maybe add or remove some formatting extensions?

Comment: What formatting plugins are you using? You can disable them for this file or file type.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tweaked around some settings.json in vscode and found my solution:
add the following lines

```
"[django-html]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": true,
      "comments": true,
      "strings": true
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "batisteo.vscode-django"
  },
```

[image]

My assumption to this solution is that, earlier this `[django-html]` settings was not instantiated so by default a `django-html` template was getting formatted through `[html]` settings as seen in the image below (pls correct me if my assumption is wrong).